# Django social auth check for email ending

Tags: django, django-socialauth

have one question, how to check email ending via django social auth? For example I want that to my site could connect peoples who have email with @example.com ending.

Comment: Email is stored in the user instance, you can check for that there

Answer (score 2):

Add a [pipeline](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html) entry that does the check, something like this should do the trick:

```
def check_email(details, *args, **kwargs):
    email = details['email']
    if not email.endswith('@example.com'):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/invalid-email')
```

Put that before the `create_user` entry and. Take into account that some providers don't return the email (like Twitter).

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using the google backend you can use the GOOGLE_WHITE_LISTED_DOMAINS setting.

Set it to a list of domains to restrict users to.

```
GOOGLE_WHITE_LISTED_DOMAINS = ['somedomain.com', 'anotherdomain.com']
```

More info here:

http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/google.html